# Unknown protocol: wss: in Socket.IO in Android

Tags: android, socket.io

Why is the

```
Socket mSocket = IO.socket("wss://engine_url:443/path_to_script);
```

returns the **URISyntaxException: Unknown protocol: wss:** exception

Any Idea why? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use `http://` or `https://`. They are actually the same with `ws://` and `wss://`

Comment: I tried that too... But I couldn't connect with the engine.

Comment: the socket.io java client did not support wss protocol. but the javascript version works with wss protocol.  From my server side, even javascript cannot work with https, it seems my server side didnot support https.

Comment: It seems to be true .. that WSS/WS protocol not being supported yet per non-JS framework

Answer (score 1):

The SocketIO Java library documentation provides sample code to connection on a secure websocket.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Other knowledge required to process their code sample.
https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/